# Adding conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

> results in "run-time error '-2147417848'(80010108)'"

I have some code that creates a new workbook, imports a little bit of data, and then adds conditional formatting to it.

**Problem:** It doesn't work, citing the error in the subject line. The problem isn't the method the error cites, the problem is that the code actually didn't add the `FormatCondition` - this is visible in the CF window afterwards - so all methods I attempt to call invariably fails with the same error.

...*unless* I step through the code from the start; in that case, it works as expected - the `FormatCondition` gets added normally, no errors in sight, and the CF is visible on the sheet doing exactly what I want it to do.

Screenshot:
[image]

Relevant code:

```
Public wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Sub Main()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    ' Populate ws with some data
    Call FixCF(ws)
End Sub

Sub FixCF(ByRef cfWs As Worksheet)
    cfWs.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    Debug.Print "Start CF"
    With cfWs.Range("G:G").FormatConditions
        .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=(INDIREKTE(ADRESSE(RAD(); 12))=""G"")"
        .Item(1).SetFirstPriority
        .Item(1).Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Item(1).Interior.Color = 14277081
        .Item(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried this variant as well:

```
cfWs.Range("G:G").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=(INDIREKTE(ADRESSE(RAD(); 12))=""G"")"
With cfWs.Range("G:G").FormatConditions(1)
    .SetFirstPriority
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.Color = 14277081
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

Here's the code the macro recorder spits out:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=(INDIREKTE(ADRESSE(RAD(); 12))=""G"")"

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

I'm not using what I've surmised via Google to be the usual culprits - `ActiveSheet` and `Selection` - and I've tried both `Application.Wait` and `DoEvents` with no change in behavior. I'm assuming it isn't an issue with corrupt workbook since I'm creating a new one on every run of the macro - but I've tried making an entirely new workbook with the same code just to be sure, and I get the same error. I've closed and reopened the "host sheet" (including the entire Excel application) many times - still nothing.

So my question remains: Why does the code only work when I step through it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have declared **ws** as public, then pass that into `FixCF` function and then use `ws` to delete conditional formatting and `cfWs` to add?

Comment: `cfWs` was originally `ws` - but I changed that to rule out confusion about which object was being referenced. Updating `ws` to `cfWs` doesn't do anything, but I'll update the code in the question as well now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works when I step through the code, is because I'm looking at the sheet when I do so. Adding a simple `cfWs.Activate` at the top of the perpetrating sub fixes everything.

@Zac mentions that it works if you use the sheet's name instead of its index. I have yet to try it, but I'll include it here for anyone who finds this post with the same problem.

So it appears that the lesson is *you can't always add conditional formatting to a sheet unless it's also the active sheet* - a little tidbit that, as far as I know, [doesn't appear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/formatcondition-object-excel) [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/formatconditions-add-method-excel).

Comment: It worked for me even when the sheet was not active. Difference is that I am using the name of the sheet to qualify the sheet rather than `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)` (so I have it as `ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")`. This means that I don't have to have the worksheet active

Comment: @Zac Thanks, I modified the answer a little to include your finding. Although, it's perplexing if that really does make a difference...